# PDO - SQL not working without any warning

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, phpmyadmin

I wrote a function to insert what i want in any database :

```
public function insert($db, $array_label, $array_value){
    $DB = new PDO('mysql:host='.$_SESSION['mysql'][0].';dbname='.$_SESSION['mysql'][1].';charset=utf8', $_SESSION['mysql'][2], $_SESSION['mysql'][3]);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO '".$db."' (";

    for($i = 0; $i < count($array_label); $i++){
        if($i > 0)
            $sql .= ", ";

        $sql .= "'".$array_label[$i]."'";
    }

    $sql .= ") VALUES (";

    for($i = 0; $i < count($array_label); $i++){
        if($i > 0)
            $sql .= ", ";

        $sql .= ":".$array_label[$i];
    }
    $sql .= ")";

    $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
    echo '\$DB->prepare("'.$sql.'");';//DEBUG

    for($i = 0; $i < count($array_label); $i++){
        $label = ":".$array_label[$i];
        $stmt->bindParam("$label", $array_value[$i]);
        echo '</br>\$stmt->bindValue("'.$label.'", '.$array_value[$i].')';//DEBUG
    }

    $stmt->execute;
    echo "</br></br>Requ&ecirc;te OK.";
}
```

}

Then, i use it like this :

```
$array_label = array('ID', 'ID_lang', 'ID_entry_cat', 'date', 'label', 'content');
$array_value = array($ID, $ID_lang, $ID_entry_cat, "2016-03-03 00:00:00", $label, $content);
 $DB->insert('entry', $array_label, $array_value);
```

After doing a lot of test, it may have a syntax problem, but i wasn't able to figure out where.

Here is what i got from the echo's(//DEBUG) :

```
$DB->prepare("INSERT INTO 'entry' ('ID', 'ID_lang', 'ID_entry_cat', 'date', 'label', 'content') VALUES (:ID, :ID_lang, :ID_entry_cat, :date, :label, :content)");
\$stmt->bindValue(":ID", 1)
\$stmt->bindValue(":ID_lang", 1)
\$stmt->bindValue(":ID_entry_cat", 1)
\$stmt->bindValue(":date", 2016-03-03 00:00:00)
\$stmt->bindValue(":label", dsqfsdq)
\$stmt->bindValue(":content", sdqfdsqf)
```

*I know there is plenty topics on PDO not returning error but :
After reading a lot of them, it didn't help me at all.
Let say this : I'm a complete noob with PDO.*

**The echo i showed to you is what my function is doing.**

I enclosed some pictures of my db to help :

[image]
[image]

PS: i leaved out "date" but it's not supposed to make troubles. I tested the same thing with it and it did the same thing : nothing.

Comment: `$stmt->execute;` is a typo right?

Comment: Null isnt allowed in date field. What did you try to put there? What value?

Comment: PhpMyAdmin fill the field with something if you put nothing.

Comment: You are using PDO in this case and I bet it tries to add NULL / nothing to the field which is causing it to fail because field isnt allowed to contain NULL or nothing

Comment: Even with a fake date -> "2016-03-03 00:00:00" , it doesn't work.

Comment: Is ID_lang foreign key or just an index? Might be the foreign key doesnt exist?

Comment: @ksno Yes ID_lang and ID_entry_cat are foreign key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace bindparam with bindvalue since you are passing values of that array:
EDIT
you also have quotes for table and column names,I replaced them with backticks and also you are missing brackets for execute

```
 function insert($db, $array_label, $array_value){
        $DB = new PDO('mysql:host='.$_SESSION['mysql'][0].';dbname='.$_SESSION['mysql'][1].';charset=utf8', $_SESSION['mysql'][2], $_SESSION['mysql'][3]);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `".$db."` (";

    for($i = 0; $i < count($array_label); $i++){
        if($i > 0)
            $sql .= ", ";

        $sql .= "`".$array_label[$i]."`";
    }

    $sql .= ") VALUES (";

    for($i = 0; $i < count($array_label); $i++){
        if($i > 0)
            $sql .= ", ";

        $sql .= ":".$array_label[$i];
    }
    $sql .= ")";

    $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
    echo '\$DB->prepare("'.$sql.'");';//DEBUG

    for($i = 0; $i < count($array_label); $i++){
        $label = ":".$array_label[$i];
        $stmt->bindValue("$label", "$array_value[$i]");
        echo '</br>\$stmt->bindValue("'.$label.'", "'.$array_value[$i].'")';//DEBUG
    }

    $stmt->execute();
    echo "</br></br>Requ&ecirc;te OK.";
}
```

Comment: bindValue() type i guess

Comment: Not working either :/ . I don't understand why you put "'. and ."' so i only changed for bindvalue.

Comment: @Madz Edit your question with the echo for this option.

Comment: @Madz I`ll test it on my machine,hold on

Comment: Thanks a lot, your code is working ! Quotes are '' or "" ? Sorry i don't know rhe english for '' and "".

Comment: @Madz Single or double quotes are for VALUES (string or dates),backticks are for table and  column names.Common beginner mistake

Comment: Not really a 'beginner mistake'. I don't know what are 'backticks'. this -> / ?
(i'm not an english native speaker) Anyway, thanks a lot, now it's finally working :)

Answer (score 0):

Try running PDO in Exception mode, you can then catch PDO exceptions:

```
$db_pdo = new PDO($db_dsn, $dbuser, $dbpassword);
$db_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// its function
$stmt->execute();
```

Also turn on error reporting in PHP to see whats going on

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunatly, It did nothing :/

Comment: do try {} catch (PDOException $e) { ..} with pdo statements

Comment: [do NOT try {} catch (PDOException $e) { ..} with pdo statements](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors)